# how to make UIImage work in Xcode of Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage

I want to show a `UIImage` with following code:

```
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc ]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500)];
image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
[self.view addSubview:image];
```

And here is my Xcode config screenshot, just drag and drop the `gifs` folder into the Xcode with `copy if necessary`

[image]

Comment: give it a abackground color and check again please

Comment: Have you changed the extension (from .gif to.png etc).

Comment: check this code on another image  not in gifs folder may be image corrupted

Comment: add the image in Asset.xcassets ,and set like this image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1"];

Comment: @PramodTapaniya the png file was intended to be put there so I could try if other formats other than gif works :D

Comment: @SaurabhJain but I don't know how to put this stuff in the `assets` ... yet

Comment: @armnotstrong If you directly change extension of the image, then it will not show because file format and extension will mismatch.

Comment: @PramodTapaniya I am awared of that so I just got a png format file there :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this.

```
image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gifs/1.png"];
```

How to add image folders
[image: How to add image folders]

Comment: Hey, thanks, this works, but I was told that Xcode will automatically try to find the file thus I didn't have to add a `gifs/` prefix. :D

Comment: Because you add the gifs as a folder(displayed as blue color), if you changed it to reference(displayed as yellow color), no folder name is required.

Comment: could you give more hint about how to make this "reference" with Xcode? I have already choose to `create folder reference` when dragging the folder to the Xcode

Comment: Updated the answer. I usually add the folder like that, and it works. Sorry for the wrong comment. When it was added by reference, the folder name was needed and it was displayed as blue. Usually Create groups is OK.